# Launch Watir/Selenium Chrome driver binary from an arbitrary location

Tags: selenium, watir, selenium-chromedriver

I want to use Watir to start a chrome for an older version of chrome, say `/Application/Google Chrome 30.app`

Here's a ref [link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) saying chromedriver expects Chrome install at specific location:

> Mac   /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome

Here's a ref [link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location) for setting up Chrome executable in a non-standard location

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/path/to/other/chrome/binary");
```

How can I do that using Watir, given syntax like

```
driver = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you have multiple versions of Chrome installed and need to be able to select which one to run? The link that you referenced is about setting the location of the "chromedriver.exe", which is a different thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Set Binary For Specific Browser Instance**

The Chrome options can be passed from Watir to Selenium using the `:desired_capabilities` as "chromeOptions":

```
caps = {"chromeOptions" => {"binary" => 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'}}
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, desired_capabilities: caps)
```

Note about the `binary` value (from the [Chromedriver page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)):

> Path to the Chrome executable to use (on Mac OS X, this should be the
>   actual binary, not just the app. e.g., '/Applications/Google
>   Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome')

**Set Default Binary**

Instead of setting the binary for each browser, you can also set the default binary location:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Update your Selenium `driver_path` directly.

Just call this before launching your new Chrome browser window:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.driver_path = "/path/to/other/chrome/binary"
```

Of course, change the path to where your `chromedriver` is. For us, we used `Rails.root.join( "lib", "chromedriver" ).to_s` because it's dynamic to the project and we could check this into the repo and it'll just work for all of our engineers.

NOTE: `driver_path` needs to be a String, so don't pass in a `File` or `Path` object.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is not to use WatiR at all and just use the "[Selenium bindings](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings)" instead.   I think the syntax is easier to grok anyways.   I would trust the Selenium bindings better, as far as consuming that ChromeOptions binary location parameter.