# Watir won't open Firefox

Tags: firefox, watir, geckodriver

I'm trying to use Watir with Firefox:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, options: {prefs: {'intl'=> {'accept_languages'=> 'en-US'}}}
```

But keep getting this error:

```
Preference values not all string or integer or boolean (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidArgumentError)
```

I've found that the issue is likely caused by Geckodriver so I've installed geckodriver-bin (0.28.0) but still no luck.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use `intl.accept_languages`:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, options: {prefs: {'intl.accept_languages' => 'en-US'}}
```

Comment: This resulted in another error: `Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line`. I found your answer from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814081/launch-watir-selenium-chrome-driver-binary-from-an-arbitrary-location) and added this line `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'` but this time got `not a file: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"` error.

Comment: Setting the binary that way should work. Is your `firefox.exe` located somewhere else?

Comment: It is actually there https://i.imgur.com/GIOyuIa.png

Comment: That's really strange. Does passing the binary as an argument give the same "not a file" error - `browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, options: {prefs: {'intl.accept_languages' => 'en-US'}, binary: 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'}`?

Comment: This time got `binary is not a Firefox executable`. Could it be caused by using WSL?

Comment: It's been a while since I tried WSL, but I remember having to jump through a bunch of hoops to launch a browser. You cannot directly access files in the Windows environment like that - you need some special `/mnt/` path (see https://superuser.com/a/1084229 as an example). Even then, I don't remember if you could run it or if you had to install Firefox within the Linux subsystem.

Comment: Thanks, Justin. Will have a proper Linux machine soon so will try it there.